# Creating secure web services with ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, security, coldfusion, wsdl, ws-security

I created an existing API with web services using ColdFusion that uses inline authentication but I'd like to secure it using some sort of authentication but I'm clueless where to start.

The web services are auto generated by ColdFusion by adding ?wsdl to the end of my cfcs.

When I say "" I mean that for each web service call the client must pass in a key/pass within the soapenv:body like this:

```
<apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">test</apiKey>
<apiPass xsi:type="xsd:string">test!ng</apiPass>
```

But I think I'd like to use WS-Security or basic authentication but I have no idea what I'm doing.

There seems to be no one doing what I'm asking in the CF community, which seems odd.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a fan of WSE (http://oasis-open.org/) or SOAP in general but it can be useful in integration situations, we've used it when consuming .NET web services for example.

My preference is to use an `Application.cfc` in the same directory as the web service to authenticate the request by IP and security token or username/password. We use this for our RESTful web services that others consume. Alternatively you can just code authentication as part of the web service processing itself.

If you have to use WSE you'd need to add a bunch of SOAP headers using `addSOAPRequestHeader()` when sending SOAP packets, and then check these same headers when getting responses. This can be messy but here is some code that works for us:

```
<cffunction name="AddSecurityHeaders" access="public" returntype="any" hint="This adds the security headers as defined in the WS Security section of the WSS standard. Username and password are unencrypted." output="Yes">
        <cfargument name="webSvc" required="Yes" type="any" hint="This must be a vaild web service."> 
        <cfargument name="username" required="Yes" type="string" hint="Username required by webservice being called."> 
        <cfargument name="password" required="Yes" type="string" hint="Password required by web service being called."> 
        <cfargument name="action" required="Yes" type="string" hint="Value to be inseted into wsa:Action node."> 
        <cfargument name="to" required="Yes" type="string" hint="Value to be inseted into wsa:To node."> 
        <cfargument name="mustUnderstandSecurityHdr" required="No" type="boolean" default="false" hint="This value will be inserted into the <wsse:Security> header as the 'mustUnderstand' value."> 

        <cfscript>

        var rightNow = "" ;
        var expiryTime = "" ;
        var objXmlAction = "" ;
        var objXmlMessageID = "" ;
        var objXmlTo = "" ;
        var objXmlSecurity = "" ;
        var objXmlReplyTo = "" ;
        var objTimezone = CreateObject("component", "com.utils.timezone") ;

        // Setup times (UTC/GMT only!)
        rightNow = objTimezone.castToUTC(Now()) ;
        expiryTime = DateAdd("n", 5, rightNow) ;

        // Create XML doument and add required nodes starting with <wsa:Action>
        objXmlAction = XmlNew() ;
        objXmlAction.XmlRoot = XmlElemNew(objXmlAction,  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing", "wsa:Action") ;
        objXmlAction.XmlRoot.XmlText = ARGUMENTS.action ;

        // ..then <wsa:MessageID>
        objXmlMessageID = XmlNew() ;
        objXmlMessageID.XmlRoot = XmlElemNew(objXmlMessageID,  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing", "wsa:MessageID") ;
        objXmlMessageID.XmlRoot.XmlText = "uuid:" & CreateUUID() ;

        // ...then <wsa:Address>
        objXmlReplyTo = XmlNew() ;
        objXmlReplyTo.XmlRoot = XmlElemNew(objXmlReplyTo,  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing", "wsa:ReplyTo") ;
        objXmlReplyTo.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(objXmlReplyTo,  "wsa:Address") ;
        objXmlReplyTo.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1].XmlText = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous" ;

        // ..then <wsa:To>
        objXmlTo = XmlNew() ;
        objXmlTo.XmlRoot = XmlElemNew(objXmlTo,  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing", "wsa:To") ;
        objXmlTo.XmlRoot.XmlText = ARGUMENTS.to ;

        // ..then the main <wsse:Security> node which contains further info...
        objXmlSecurity = XmlNew(true) ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity,  "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse:Security") ;
        // ...note: this namespace is added as it is used in children nodes and this can help avoid XmlSearch errors in CFMX
        //StructInsert(objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XmlAttributes, "xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd") ;

         // ...Timestamp, it's children and attributes
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity,  "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "wsu:Timestamp") ;
        StructInsert(objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1].XmlAttributes, "wsu:Id", "Timestamp-#CreateUUID()#") ;

        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1].XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "wsu:Created") ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1].XmlChildren[1].XmlText = DateFormat(rightNow, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "T" & TimeFormat(rightNow, "HH:mm:ss") & "Z" ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1].XmlChildren[2] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "wsu:Expires") ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[1].XmlChildren[2].XmlText = DateFormat(expiryTime, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "T" & TimeFormat(expiryTime, "HH:mm:ss") & "Z" ;
        // ...Username token, attributes and children 
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity,  "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse:UsernameToken") ;
        StructInsert(objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlAttributes, "xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd") ;
        StructInsert(objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlAttributes, "wsu:Id", "SecurityToken-#CreateUUID()#") ;
        // ...UsernameToken.Username
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity, "wsse:Username") ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[1].XmlText = Trim(ARGUMENTS.username) ;
        // ...UsernameToken.Password 
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[2] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity, "wsse:Password") ;
        StructInsert(objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[2].XmlAttributes, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0##PasswordText") ; 
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[2].XmlText = Trim(ARGUMENTS.password) ;
        // ... Nonce 
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[3] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse:Nonce") ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[3].XmlText = ToBase64(CreateUUID()) ;
        // ...Created 
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[4] = XmlElemNew(objXmlSecurity, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "wsu:Created") ;
        objXmlSecurity.XmlRoot.XMLChildren[2].XmlChildren[4].XmlText = DateFormat(rightNow, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "T" & TimeFormat(rightNow, "HH:mm:ss") & "Z" ;

        // Add the created headers to the soap requests - note that the 2nd and 3rd parameters have no significance in this instance
        addSOAPRequestHeader(ARGUMENTS.webSvc, "sia1", "hd1", "#objXmlAction#", false) ;
        addSOAPRequestHeader(ARGUMENTS.webSvc, "sia1", "hd1", "#objXmlMessageID#", false) ;
        addSOAPRequestHeader(ARGUMENTS.webSvc, "sia1", "hd1", "#objXmlReplyTo#", false) ;
        addSOAPRequestHeader(ARGUMENTS.webSvc, "sia1", "hd1", "#objXmlTo#", false) ;
        addSOAPRequestHeader(ARGUMENTS.webSvc, "sia1", "hd1", "#objXmlSecurity#", ARGUMENTS.mustUnderstandSecurityHdr) ;

        return ARGUMENTS.webSvc ;

        </cfscript>

    </cffunction>
```

Here is an example of use:

```
// Create web service
objWebSvc = CreateObject("webservice", "remoteWebService?WSDL") ;

// Create security object and add the security header to our SOAP request
objWSESecurity = CreateObject("component", "wse") ;

objWebSvc = objWSESecurity.AddSecurityHeaders(
    webSvc=objWebSvc,
    username="xxx", 
    password="yyy", 
    action="remoteAction", 
    to="remoteWebService", 
    mustUnderstandSecurityHdr=false
) ;
```

You see - lots of code :) Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I understand what your function does but I'm not exactly sure where to place it or how to call it. I'm serving up my webservices like this http://mysite.com/news.cfc?wsdl - now how to I get this function to intercept the call to the cfc? Sorry for my confusion and thanks again.

Comment: I've updated the code above, but it's interesting to note that we've moved away from WSE with this integration - it was seen as a source of trouble and not worth the effort. They now authenticate as part of their service request based on authentication credentials we pass.